# Issue with NSDateformatter while converting NSDate to format "MMM, YYYY"

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have `NSDate` with value `2015-12-27 +0000` and when I convert this `NSDate` to `NSString` with format `MMM, YYYY` I am getting:

NSString as `Dec, 2016`

Comment: Can you include your code that is exhibiting this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the capital Y in your date format specifies the year in the [ISO week date system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), not the Gregorian calendar.

I imagine your code may look something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM, YYYY"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [df stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Instead try using the format:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM, yyyy"];
```

When using format strings such as this to specify your output format, NSDateFormatter uses the conventions from [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (which describes the difference between Y and y if you want more detail).